# Unable to run dotnet core 2 console app in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, autofac, windows-server-2008-r2, topshelf

I'm developing a windows service application using TopShelf and under dotnet core 2 framework. To create it I used Console App (.NET core) template. Now, to deploy the App I created a publish profile to do it locally. This is the content:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
  <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <PublishDir>C:\Repos\Deployments\MassTransit.Consumer</PublishDir>
  <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
  <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see the RuntineIdentifier is **win7-x64**, which according with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) this should be the correct one to run the application in Windows server 2008 R2. When I deploy the application to the local folder I can run it without issues in my machine executing the generated .exe, but when I try to run it in Windows server 2008 R2, copying all the files of the local folder in the windows server, I'm getting ***badimageformatexception bad il format error***:

[image: Console Error]

In windows server  is installed **Dotnetcore.2.0.5-WindowsHosting** and **Dotnet-sdk-2.1.105-win64**

Just a FYI,I have a web api core 2 application running under IIS in this server and if I run **dotnet --version** in cmd.exe it returns 2.1.0.105, so it recognize that dotnet core is installed

Any clue why the console app is getting me that error at the time to run it in Windows Server 2008 R2. Do I need to install anything else? Or, do I need to change something in my publish profile?

### Update

I'm pretty sure the exception is happening in the yellow line by the `Load.From`:

[image: Code]

I'm using that code to load custom libraries that have Autofac modules I need to register when the app start.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the needed dlls to run the app on the server?

Comment: Yes, I copied all the files that are generated when I publish the project and it runs in my local machine. I also used `dotnet publish` command and it was the same result. The command I ran was `dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x64`. When I dll is missing the console let me know what file I need to add, and it's giving the pointed error instead. Have you run a console dotnet core 2 console application in Windows Server 2008 R2 in the past?

Comment: For Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2, there should be other dependencies listed the documentation.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I have updated the question with new info, do you have Idea what could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a server's problem. It was because the pattern I'm trying to match was contained in the filename, which is a path, so it was loading wrong assemblies like `hostfrx.dll` and `hostpolicy.dll`:

[image: Assemblies]

It was running locally because this assemblies show up once I deploy the project.